# urllib.request.urlopen(url) returns an empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am crawling a website 24/7 and downloading the pages with

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

However, sometimes (with no apparent reason) the result is an empty string. It happens in different pages, different times. No special pattern - just returns an empty string sometimes.

Any ideas why this can happen?

Comment: We don't know your code, we don't know what site gave you the problem, and we won't be able to reproduce the error.  You're going to need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: Thanks! I know, I am asking in general if there is a reason (e.g. some headers that should be sent, maybe some timeout...I don't know). Is there any "general" reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach that could help you.

```
import requests

urls = ['http://www.news.com',
        'http://www.cnn.com',
]

failed_urls = []
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    # Some of the things you can check
    print(url)
    print(r.history)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)

    # One method you could use to keep track of URls that fail
    if r.status_code != 200 or not r.content:
        failed_urls.append([url, r.status_code, r.content])
```

Comment: Though this may work, OP is asking about the `urllib` module.